# Equation in integers $x y^2 + 2 y z^2 + z x^2 = 0$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

The equation in integers
$$x y^2 + 2 y z^2 + z x^2 = 0$$
has some integral solution $[1\colon 0\colon 0]$, $[0\colon 1\colon 0]$, $[0\colon 0\colon 1]$, $[1\colon -1 \colon 1]$. I wonder if there are other  solutions ( non-proportional to the one listed).

Notes: If we expand $(x + y \sqrt[3]{2} + z \sqrt[3]{4})^3$ the coefficient of $\sqrt[3]{4}$ is $3(x y^2 + 2 y z^2 + z x^2)$. I was looking for an $x + y \sqrt[3]{2}+ z\sqrt[3]{4}$ such that
$$(x + y \sqrt[3]{2}+ z\sqrt[3]{4})^3= a+b \sqrt[3]{2}$$
We have the example
$$(1 - \sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4})^3= 9(-1+\sqrt[3]{2})$$
and was wondering if we could get other examples.

What I've tried: the curve above is a smooth cubic, so an elliptic curve. However, no extra rational points using secants and tangents can be gotten out of the given points.

It is easy to show that if $p\mid y$ then $p$ also divides one of the $x$, $z$, but chasing prime divisors does not seem to get a contradiction that quickly.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: $[2:-2:-1]$ and $[2:1:-1]$

Comment: @jjagmath: Thank you, a very useful observation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case where $xyz=0$ is easy, so I will skip it. Assume then that $xyz\neq 0$.

Your equation is then $(\frac{x}{z})(\frac{y}{z})^2+2(\frac{y}{z})+(\frac{x}{z})^2=0,$ that is $(\frac{xy}{z^2})^2+2(\frac{xy}{z})+(\frac{x}{z})^3=0$.

Set $u=-\frac{x}{z}$ and $v=\frac{xy}{z}+1$. Then we get $v^2-1-u^3=0$.

According to [LMFDB database](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/36/a/4) , the elliptic curve $v^2=u^3+1$ has rank $0$, and the torsion points are: $(-1,0),(0,-1),(0,1),(2,-3),(2,3)$. This should be enough to solve your question.

Comment: "If one of $x,y,z$ is $0$, you get $x=y=z=0$" Are you sure?

Comment: Oops, no...but this is an easy case. I will modify my answer accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, great answer, teachable moment!